# How can I use the same Google Analytics dashboard across my profiles

Tags: google-analytics

I track multiple sites from the same `Google Analytics` login. I took the time to setup custom widgets on the dashboard of one of the profiles thinking that I could somehow set it as the default dashboard.

I cannot find that option. How can I share the same dashboard across GA Profiles without having to manually setup each (not really an option as there are > 10 sites needing to be changed).